# How to reframe such multi header data frame in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-header pandas data frame as follows.

```
           2018-03      2018-05      2018-07
unique_id   a   b        a   b        a   b

  1197      4   5        1   2        4   6
  1203      1   0        3   8        2   2
```

where 2018-03,2018-05 and 2018-07 are representing 3 months of the year 2018. Under each month, two attributes  'a' and 'b' are there. There is also one unique id there.

I want to reframe the above data frame into a single header data frame with three columns 'unique_id', 'month', and 'a'. Desired output will be as follows.

```
unique_id     month      a

  1197       2018-03     4
  1197       2018-05     1
  1197       2018-07     4
  1203       2018-03     1
  1203       2018-05     3
  1203       2018-07     2
```

Can you please provide me the python code?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your data is stored in df variable:

```
new_data = []
for _,row in df.iterrows():
    for head_mon,head_letter in df.columns[::2]:
        new_data.append([row['unique_id'],
                         head_mon,
                         row[head_mon]['a']])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['unique_id', 'month', 'a'])
```